# How the transfer learning is achieved by pre_trained_model.get_layer() in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am following [this](https://github.com/https-deeplearning-ai/tensorflow-1-public/blob/main/C2/W3/ungraded_lab/C2_W3_Lab_1_transfer_learning.ipynb) tutorial to achieve transfer learning by TF.

The main idea is to extract the layers in `InceptionV3` from the beginning up to `mixed7`, and add flatten, dense, dropout and dense layers to customise the end layers.

```py
from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
from tensorflow.keras import layers
local_weights_file = '/tmp/inception_v3_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5'
pre_trained_model = InceptionV3(input_shape = (150, 150, 3), 
                                include_top = False, 
                                weights = None)
pre_trained_model.load_weights(local_weights_file)
for layer in pre_trained_model.layers:
  layer.trainable = False
pre_trained_model.summary()
# Summary of all the layers in InceptionV3

last_layer = pre_trained_model.get_layer('mixed7')
print('last layer output shape: ', last_layer.output_shape)
last_output = last_layer.output
# last layer output shape:  (None, 7, 7, 768)

x = layers.Flatten()(last_output)
x = layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)                  
x = layers.Dense  (1, activation='sigmoid')(x)           

# Append the dense network to the base model
model = Model(pre_trained_model.input, x) 

model.summary()
# `InceptionV3` from the beginning up to `mixed7`, plus flatten, dense, dropout and dense layers in the end
```

While the code can be run without any problem, I still do not understand how the pre-mixed7 layers are passed to the model. The `last_output` (shape (None, 7, 7, 768)) only contains the weights/bias from `mixed7`, though I know these weights/bias are calculated all the way from the beginning to `mixed7`. So, the `last_output` should only contain one layer, not multiple layers before `mixed7`.

Then the code adds several custom layers, i.e. flatten, dense, dropout and dense.

Then in the end, why suddenly, the code would have **the “layers before mixed7”**, plus mixed7, plus the added customised end layers?

I have asked this at [here](https://community.deeplearning.ai/t/why-model-model-pre-trained-model-input-x-would-include-the-layers-before-mixed7/577484/8), but still could not follow it.

Comment: Can u add more details on your this state `Then, why suddenly, the code would have the “layers before mixed7”, plus mixed7, plus the added customised end layers?`??

Comment: I added more details for my confusion.